# Cannot read props of undefined in export funtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to create a global function page so I can reuse my code. However, I am getting an error and was wondering why this is undefined.

```
function clickUserProfile(id){
    console.log(this);
    if(id !== this.props.match.params.id){
        this.props.history.push('/profile/' + id);
    }
}

export function test(){
//code
serprofilepic.onclick = () => clickUserProfile(user_id);
//code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this.props` within a global function. `this` is not defined because you are not in a class.

Comment: Is there an alternate way to route in a global function other than using this.props.history.push?

Comment: @James You could try passing in `this.props` as an argument to `clickUserProfile()`. So maybe something like `clickUserProfile(id, props)`